# ZFS on production server don't want to force mount on boot

Tags: mount, zfs, gentoo

I use ZFS on production remote gentoo server. All was fine, until my server freezed and I needed to reboot it. 
It failed with 'device or resource busy' error on mounting rootfs. 
The simply action need to avoid this - import and export it. But for me it was really hard. remote management virtual cd mount is very slow, buggy, and what I did was boot from live cd, import -f pool and export it. But why it is not forced at boot? Why I need to do these additional steps?

my kernel line is:
linux /kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.9.11-hardened real_root=ZFS=mypool/ROOT/rootfs dozfs=force by=id net.ifnames=0 zfsforce=1
zfs version is 0.6.5.9

I have two 'force' keywords, and it ignores this! What to do?